# UIScrollView inside UIScrollView – ignore scroll view touches when in bounds of text view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, first-responder

I have one `UIScrollView` inside another `UIScrollView`, both scrolling vertically. I’m having an issue where when I try to scroll the inner scroll view, the touches are also picked up just afterwards by the outer scroll view. I need touches in the inner scroll view to be exclusively handled by it, and for `scrollViewDidScroll` to NOT be called on the parent scroll view.

I’ve tried all manner of things, subclassing the scroll view and overriding `hitTest:withEvent`, setting `canCancelContentTouches`, setting `exclusiveTouch`, nothing work at all. The `scrollViewDidScroll` methods are fired first on the inner one, then on the outer one.

How can I effectively kill the touch after the first scroll view, and not pass it up the responder chain to the outer scroll view?

(FYI: The hierarchy is that there’s a child view controller inbetween, so the outer scroll view contains a child view controller, which in turn contains the inner scroll view).

Answer (score 0):

Apple definitely DOES NOT discourage UIScrollView inside UIScrollView. It's actually in the doc:

> your application does not need to do anything to support nesting scrolling. It is supported and provided by default.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html

If you want to disable the parent scroll view from scrolling, you can probably send a notification from the child, and set `isScrollEnabled` in parent.